# Replacing words from array in a string

Tags: c#, string

If I've got a string:

```
How much wood would a woodchuck chuck
if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
Just as much as a woodchuck would
if a woodchuck could chuck wood.
```

and I want to replace these words with `""`:

```
wood, chuck, if
```

and this is my code:

```
string[] words = new string[] { "wood", "chuck", "if" };
string input = woodchuckText;
string output = string.Empty;

foreach (string word in words)
{
  output = input.Replace(word, string.Empty);
}

Console.Write(output);
```

why it only replaces the last word instead of replacing them all?

Comment: do you also want to remove woodchuck from the string? because it is wood and chuck?

Comment: it doesn't you just overwrite the first two traversals, you need `output = woodchuckText;` and then `output.Replace...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you  are iterating always on the original  copy of `Input` and in last  iteration only the last replace will take effect and hence you got the `output`  result

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
  input = input.Replace(word, string.Empty);
}
 output  =  input;
```

**Hint**

try  for example to put a breakpoint on `output = input.Replace(word, string.Empty);` by pressing `F9` and u will  see  what's  the output

**or**

just place `Console.Write(output);` in the foreach loop

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
  output = input.Replace(word, string.Empty);
  Console.Write(output); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`input` never changes after the replacement, so basically the output you are getting is the same as if you only replaced the last of your words.

To resolve this, do this instead:

```
output = input;

foreach (string word in words)
 {
  output = output.Replace(word, string.Empty);
 }
```

Comment: oh snap, I missed it... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use regular expression:

```
string[] words = new string[] { "wood", "chuck", "if" };
var output = Regex.Replace(input, String.Join("|", words), "");
```

Comment: I  think the OP seek to understand the reason not an alternative :)

Comment: What I did is a rookie mistake ^^. Alternatives are interesting tho.

Comment: @K.B ah, missed that, then your answer is correct, and let alternative live)

Answer (score 1):

Because each iteration you are setting the `output` to the original `input` string. Therefore only the last iteration will be set on `output`. Adjust logic to keep updating the same string:

```
string[] words = new string[] { "wood", "chuck", "if" };
string input = woodchuckText;
string output = input;

foreach (string word in words)
{
  output = output.Replace(word, string.Empty);
}

Console.Write(output);
```